# multiple requests via php curl affects my vps speed

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, curl

I have a problem and can't find any solution for it. I have VPS from ovh with ram 64GB and three cores CPU is dedicated, not shared (A), and VPS for external checking (B). my problem is that my site hosted on VPS (A) has the option to check the item before buying, and I put an external link to VPS (B) for the checking process in the PHP backend in the leading site. And sometimes, many clients click on the check button at the same time. I found the VPS (A), which hosts the main site. But, it isn't opening due to multiple requests and slowly opens. i send the curl requests to VPS (B) from VPS (A).

**Curl code post method**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd()."/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd()."/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $error ? json_encode(array('status' => 3, 
    'result' => 'Time out for Request', 'data' => "")) : $data;
```

My project works with laravel and PHP, and MySQL. My VPS (A) is ubuntu 20, works with Nginx, same as VPS B. Now I want a solution to this problem. Is it related to my curl code or my VPS settings? How can I handle these multiple curl requests coming from buyers?

I tried to make multiple VPSs as VPS (B) and rotate them, but still the same problem. VPS A still slowly when many clients come.

Comment: Additional information request from A and B, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively playing the roles of two people here, *both* of whom can work to make this better...

### As person B, you are running a web service which provides some data.

You can work to make that web service as efficient as possible, for example check for unnecessary or inefficient calls to the database, or anything stateful that would cause locking. Use a profiler to find where the slowest parts of your code are - don't guess and waste time optimising things which are already fast.

You can implement caching so that repeated requests can be served without re-fetching the data. You can send cache lifetime headers to help clients cache the response on their end.

You can implement timeouts and rate limits, so that it fails more gracefully under high load, returning results to some users and useful errors to others.

You can of course throw more hardware at the problem - but make sure you work out where the bottleneck is first. If you haven't already, put the database and web server on separate servers or containers, so they're not competing for CPU and RAM. If the web server is running out of CPU or network capacity, consider "scaling out", putting multiple web servers in front of one database.

### As person A, you are requesting data from a web service

You can implement caching, either of the data, or of the HTTP responses, so that you don't need to call the service as often. You can ask the author of the web service (yourself!) to help with this by including cache lifetime information in responses.

You can rate limit how often a single user can press the button, so that they can't overload the remote service.

You can implement client-side timeouts and handle failures gracefully, falling back to old cached data or a useful error message if the service is not responsive.

You'll probably benefit from using a third-party library like Guzzle or Symfony HTTP Client rather than crafting curl calls manually. They won't be automatically faster, but they'll make implementing things like caching and timeouts a lot easier than the very low-level functions built into PHP.

Comment: 1st i  already rate limit each user for 3 check requests per one time, 2nd i can't use guzzle library because i want specific cookies file in the process of checking, 3rd the website is well coded also the checking process takes no time if two clients check at the same time but the problem is i got about 10 or more people click on the checking button finally do you see that if i use guzzle or symfony does this will affect in the requests speed and fix this issue or its same as the manually curl

Comment: @ShehabMohamed There is no magic wand you can wave and make everything faster, and I can't go through your application for you, you have to do some investigation and see what will help your specific case. The need to store cookies (which I am absolutely sure is possible with Guzzle by the way) is a sign that your web service is doing something stateful - maybe writing a PHP session? If so, that's very likely to cause bottlenecks and locking, and would be a great place to start - e.g. if it's for authentication, look into using something like JWT rather than a stateful session.